# Is Chef/Puppet too complicated?

Tags: puppet, chef, configuration-management

I know both of them are amazing tools, and have great feature sets. But maybe, just maybe, they are like Word/Excel, which I probably only use < 10% feature in my lifetime. To me, a bash-based script language would be much better than a DSL.

Is it just me?

Comment: How can any of us possibly answer this? Obviously many people find these tools invaluable. This depends on your configuration, your experience, and your knowledge. This isn't a discussion site, take a look at the [faq]

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Sounds like it's too complicated **for you**. That's nice and all, but others have different use cases.

Comment: Puppet borders on being simple if you stick to the basic, File/Package/Service resources, which will give you ton of useful functionality.  Like every other tool there are lots of advanced features that you probably don't need, but they are there because somebody needs them.  If you want to learn puppet, then pick up a copy of Pro Puppet.  http://www.amazon.com/dp/1430230576/  It is a really good technical book.

Comment: You've asked this exact question on Reddit, Linkedin, and now here with pretty much the same response. Perhaps it's time to actually try a config management system rather than imagine you can easily create your own with Bash?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Puppet and Chef are complicated and have a steep learning curve. What are you looking to accomplish? There are lighter-weight [configuration management tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_configuration_management_software) out there.

Comment: Yes, whenever I tried to write the recipe in chef/puppet for our riak deployment, I started to miss the command line. And https://github.com/cmer/shoestrap looks quite interesting. Want to find out whether others feel the same.

Comment: I don't know about you, but I find puppet manifests tend to be less complicated and far clearer, then many scripts I have seen.